# Snap version of Atom doesn't open

Tags: snap, atom

I am not able to launch atom IDE text editor which I installed via snap about a year ago, although it was running fine until today. I tried launching it both through the interface (by clicking on the icon) and using the command line (simply typing `atom`). In the first case I can see that Atom is trying to load in the top menu bar (icon appears for about 10 seconds, but then disappears and nothing happens). When I run it from the command line, absolutely nothing happens and a new command prompt immediately appears on the next line. I also restarted the computer: same result.

Some context:

- version of atom: 1.54.0 (installed via snap)
- version of Ubuntu: 18.04 LTS

Also, I though it might be a problem with snap packages in general, so I launched PyCharm Community (another snap program which I have), and it opened normally.

Comment: What does /var/log/syslog say about your attempt to open the snap?

Comment: I get this line in syslog just after launching atom: `Jan 20 23:06:40 PC-PACHA atom_atom.desktop[4548]: /snap/atom/270/bin/launcher: line 11: [: missing `]' `
I have no idea how to interpret it :/

Comment: Followed by this line: `Jan 20 23:06:41 PC-PACHA kernel: [  581.919855] atom[4570]: segfault at 1 ip 00007fbc274867b8 sp 00007fff55510dd8 error 6 in libc-2.31.so[7fbc2731d000+178000]`

Comment: It's a typo in a snap-provided file. You can't fix it, since Snaps are read-only. File a bug with the Snap creator. They need to see those syslog lines.

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

Just go to the [main website](https://atom.io/) and install Atom's `.deb` package into your Downloads directory.
Then use `dpkg -i` to install the package or use the `GUI installer` by clicking on the downloaded `.deb` file and it will reinstall it for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will try. But will that just install a seperate version of atom, or replace my current install entirely ?

Comment: I'd suggest uninstalling the snapd version and sticking with the other one to ensure that everything will work fine.

Comment: I solved the issue by uninstalling the snap package and reinstalling Atom using apt-get, as they suggest in the Atom documentation [here](https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/).

Comment: Funnily enough, all the packages which I had installed on the snap version were all already installed, which was quite surprising

Comment: @MazenSaad almost of an year of suffer came to and end... now it's working again!